# How to parse a string/stream_get_contents

Tags: php, regex

I will use exec PHP function to run a command and get the response, something like this:

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($conn, 'php -v');
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
$data= stream_get_contents($stream_out);
```

I am expecting that the data that is returned is in a table format, example below:

[image]

So I am interested in getting the `Userid` values. What is the best way to do that? Maybe link to possible PHP functions to use?

Most of posts on stackoverflow suggest `substr`, but I don't think that I can use it because the table may be bigger or smaller.

Comment: What sort of table? An html table? json reflecting a 2d array? a dump from a database table? a csv grid?

Comment: something like when you execute linux command who.

Comment: i believe that the table will end up as a string when getting the output ($data= stream_get_contents($stream_out);)

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't post your data (or an excerpt of your data)

Comment: that data looks exactly like the image above , except that the table will be constructed by characters such as - , _ , | ,spaces and line breaks

Comment: @boomby post a complete example of at least one row of data please

Comment: here is an exemple:
--------------Table1-----------
fname | lname | userid
-----------------------------------
jakson    jack        3 
nils         smith       44 . PS when posting the spaces and line breaks gets removed, thats why i uploaded an image instead

Comment: @boomby: please update the question with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that your input looks like

```
--------------Table1----------- 
fname | lname | userid 
----------------------------------- 
 jakson   jack          3
 nils        smith       44
```

You can use a simple regex with `preg_match_all`:

```
(?m)\d+(?=\s*$)
```

**REGEX EXPLANATION**:

- `(?m)` forces `$` to match at the end of a line, not at the end of the whole input string
- `\d+` will match one or more digits from 0 to 9 and thus will match the IDs
- `(?=\s*$)` - the lookahead checking for optional whitespace (`\s*` where `\s` stands for `\r\n\f\t` and a space, and `*` is a quantifier meaning 0 or more occurrences of the preceding subpattern) and line end (`$`). Note that lookaheads do not consume text and they are never part of a match.

In PHP, you need to declare a regex with delimiters, e.g.

```
$pattern = "#\d+(?=\s*$)#m";
```

Comment: I didn't know you could use modifiers like that. Can you use pairings like that as well? Is `(?mi)` valid?

Comment: Yes, `(?mi)` is valid.

Comment: i am new to regex but i did it like this: 
$pattern = "(?m)\d+(?=\s*$)";
preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $result);
and i got the following error : PHP Warning:  preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '\'

Comment: @boomby: you need to use delimiters. I prefer # as a delimiter since there are many backslashes in regex patterns as usual. The `m` modifier can be placed after the last delimiter. Result: `$pattern = "#\d+(?=\s*$)#m";`. Or `$pattern = "/\\d+(?=\\s*$)/m";`.

Comment: could you please briefly explain what that regex pattern means, what conditions are examined?